# How to get /dev/sdf back after upgraded from Maverick to Natty in EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I've just upgraded my EC2 instance to Natty, using `do-release-upgrade`.

However, the block devices `/dev/sdf`, `/dev/sdg`, ... are no longer existed.

(I've already attached EBS to these devices, though.)

Comment: what does dmesg show?  are they now sdh and sde, etc?

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 11.04 Natty on EC2, you will find the block devices on the instance have been renamed to `/dev/xvdf` and `/dev/xvdg` though you'll still need to use `/dev/sdf` and `/dev/sdg` when specifying them to the Amazon API tools like `ec2-attach-volume` and `ec2-run-instances --block-device-mapping`.